# Calculate data only for special rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table:

```
ID    count  OperationID 
100   111       1
100    55       2
100    55       3
100    66       4 
99     69       1
99     33       2
99     11       14
98     33       1
98     47       2
```

It is necessary to show data for those 'OperationID' that are in each 'ID'

Ex. output:

```
ID    count  OperationID 
100   111       1
100    55       2
99     69       1
99     33       2
98     33       1
98     47       2
```

Maybe join table with itself help?But it does not work ...

Comment: Why is `OperationId = 1` included in the result set?  It is not in `id` 90.

Comment: Sorry it's my mistake. 98 instead 90. I fixed

Comment: Show what you've tried so far and what errors or unexpected results you get.

Comment: Please, give me some idea. I have't idea(

Answer (score 1):

You can use it.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE ( ID INT, [count] INT,OperationID  INT)

INSERT INTO @MyTable
VALUES
(100,111,1),
(100,55,2),
(100,55,3),
(100,66,4 ),
(99,69,1),
(99,33,2),
(99,11,14),
(98,33,1),
(98,47,2)

SELECT  * 
FROM @MyTable 
WHERE 
    OperationID IN 
    (SELECT 
        OperationID 
    FROM @MyTable
    GROUP BY OperationID
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID) FROM @MyTable)
 )
```

Result:

```
ID          count       OperationID
----------- ----------- -----------
100         111         1
100         55          2
99          69          1
99          33          2
98          33          1
98          47          2
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok you can try this, but there are some **considerations in your dataset**, what about if there is a **row that does not have a common OpID** for example.

```
declare @tbl table (ID int,Cnt int, OperationID int)
insert into @tbl
select  100,111,1 union
select  100, 55,2 union
select  100, 55,3 union
select  100, 66,4 union 
select  99 , 69,1 union
select  99 , 33,2 union
select  99 , 11,14 union
select  98 , 33,1 union
select  98,47,2

 select * from @tbl where OperationID in (
 select OperationID from @tbl
 where id in (
select a.id from 
(
select top 1 id, count (distinct OperationID) as opCnt from @tbl
group by id
order by opCnt
) a
)
)
```

Result

```
98  33  1
98  47  2
99  33  2
99  69  1
100 55  2
100 111 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is not the most optimal way.

```
with cte1 as (
select distinct id
from Operations
), 

cte2 as (
select distinct operationID
from Operations
)
, cte3 as (
select *
from cte1 cross join cte2
)

SELECT *
FROM operations
WHERE operationid NOT IN(

SELECT cte3.operationid
FROM operations a
right JOIN cte3 ON cte3.id = a.id
AND cte3.operationid = a.operationid
WHERE a.id IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
DECLARE @table TABLE ( id INT, cnt INT, operationid INT ) 

INSERT INTO @table VALUES
 (100,111 , 1 ) 
,(100, 55 , 2 ) 
,(100, 55 , 3 ) 
,(100, 66 , 4 ) 
,(99 , 69 , 1 ) 
,(99 , 33 , 2 ) 
,(99 , 11 , 14)  
,(98 , 33 , 1 )  
,(98 , 47 , 2 )

;WITH cte
AS (
SELECT
    Count(distinct id)  TotalId
FROM
    @table
)
,cte1  as 
(select 
 operationid
,Count( distinct id)  operationid_By_Id
FROM
    @table
Group by
operationid )
SELECT * From 
@table c
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM (
    SELECT 
        * 
    FROM cte1 A 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM cte b WHERE a.operationid_By_Id = b.TotalId) 
    ) d where d.operationid = c.operationid)
Order by id desc , operationid
```